# WebFlux: Get property from flux objects and chain the flux to next

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a chain of webclient calls as shown below.

1. Get `Flux<RecordA>` from first API call
2. Get some property from Record, lets say prop, from each record (`List<Long>`)
3. Call another API to get with list of unique prop values and get the details
4. Update the `Flux<RecordA>` object values in first step with the data received from step 3 based on prop field.
5. Return the final updated records

So how can I pass the flux from step 1 to step 4?

Example:

```
Assume my ObjA is something like 
{id: Integer, prop: Long, propDescription: String}

private Flux<ObjA> getListOfObjects() {
  return webClient.get().exchangeToFlux();
}
private Flux<Props> thenGetListofPropDetails(List<Long> props) {
  return webClient.get().exchangeToFlux();
}
```

Then I want to do something like below

```
getListOfObjects()
  thenCollectPropFromEachObjA
  thenGetListofPropDetails(List of prop)
  thenUpdateEachObjAPropDescriptionFromPropDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Data
  static class ObjA {
    Integer id;
    Long prop;
  }

  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Getter
  static class Props {
    Long newProp;
  }

  private static Flux<ObjA> getListOfObjects() {
    //REPLACE WITH YOUR WEBCLIENT
    return Flux.just(new ObjA(1, 1L), new ObjA(2, 2L));
  }

  private static Flux<Props> thenGetListOfPropDetails(List<Long> props) {
    return Flux.just(new Props(3L), new Props(4L));
  }

  public FLux<ObjA> yourMethod {
    Flux<ObjA> allObjA = getListOfObjects().cache();
    Flux<Props> allProps = allObjA.map(ObjA::getProp).collectList()
                                  .flatMapMany(apr -> thenGetListOfPropDetails(apr));

    return allObjA.zipWith(allProps, (a, p) -> {
      a.setProp(p.getNewProp());
      return a;
    });
  }
```